# Aut of Plane vs Aut of Sphere

Tags: complex-analysis

So it is known that the automorphim group of the complex plane is the $\{az+b;\ a\not=0,\}$ while the automorphism group of the Riemann sphere $\mathbb C\sqcup\{\infty\}$ is $\Big\{\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d};\ ad-bc\not =0\Big\}$.

But what is the geometric interpretation of that? I mean how adding one point (one-point compactifcation) can make this change of automorphism groups?

Comment: Because when you think of an automorphism of the plane, it must leave $\infty$ fixed, whereas, in general, $\infty $ can be sent to any point of the Riemann sphere.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense .. thanks